# Create shape mask for GTK Window?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I am interested if anyone has any experience with [the following function](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--shape-combine-mask) of the `gtk.Window/gtk.Widget`

```
 shape_combine_mask(shape_mask, offset_x, offset_y)
```

I want to make the window round rather than rectangular. How do I get a shape_mask? It says that it has to be a bitmap. Should I use `gtk.Pixbuf` to get bitmap from an image? Or should I use `cairo` to get a shape with `cairo_region_create_from_surface` and then use another function that accepts the gtk.Region as a first argument?

It would be pretty rad if someone could post an example for this, C/C++ or preferably Python.

I use GTK version 2

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! :D Your answer was more than helpful! This feature I was trying to implement was just for the fanciness of the application and is not necessary so I wont switch to GTK3 but will try just for the fun of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Rehost of the sample in the first comment: https://gist.github.com/d6d31145007d2edc7706d09d955867de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question was provided by comment to the question and was implemented the same year in Python 2, using PyGTK and Cairo.

If anyone is interested on how to do this, you can see the working example here: https://github.com/stamat/droplets/blob/16b11c4ff96cf0b8e4fcdd85ee1cdc1fa8fb74e6/droplets/droplet.py#L127

Happy window shaping! ✨